# Generate new worksheets using VBA, using values from one worksheet and exporting as CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a VBA macro to pull two columns worth of data, and place on another sheet, this will be based on the first column. Easier with an example....

```
Set A   Table 1
Set A   Table 2
Set A   Table 3
Set A   Table 4
Set B   Table 5
Set B   Table 6
```

So this would generate two work sheets one, containing Set A with set A table list, and one containing set B with the set B table list.. I am then going to export all these worksheets as CSVs... My current code (below) finds none duplicate values in column A and then moves to a new sheet, I now want this to find the column B values aswell.

```
Dim wsYes As Worksheet
Set wsYes = Worksheets("YES")

With wsYes

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    myRange.Copy .Cells(1, .Columns.Count) 'copy to far right column
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count, 1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In myRange

        Dim sName As String
        sName = UCase(MyCell.Value)

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
        With wsNew
            .Name = sName
            .Range("A1").Value = "Source"
            .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A2").Value = sName
            .Range("B1").Value = "Table Name"



        End With

    Next MyCell

    myRange.Clear

End With
```

Outcome something like this

```
Source worksheet
Column A  Column B
Set A     Table 1
Set A     Table 2
Set A     Table 3 
Set B     Table 4
Set B     Table 5
Set B     Table 6 

Generated Worksheet 1
Column A  Column B
Set A     Table 1
          Table 2
          Table 3 
          ect....

Generated Worksheet 2
Column A  Column B
Set B     Table 4
          Table 5
          Table 6 
          ect....
```

All within one workbook, no external sheets.

Thanks in advance, if you need any additional info please ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow, aincre, bincre, i As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    aincre = 2
    bincre = 2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = "Set A" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & aincre) = "Set A"
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & aincre) = Cells(i, 2)
            aincre = aincre + 1
        ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "Set B" Then
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & bincre) = "Set B"
            Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & bincre) = Cells(i, 2)
              bincre = bincre + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This works fine however I was just using Set A & Set B as an example, there are around 50 different sets all with different names,

Comment: You have to modify the code as per the requirement. Hope it can be done